# Splash screen is fine, but from the grub boot loader on, the video has obviously got wrong settings: what to do?

Tags: fedora, grub, console, video

I should but don't really know what went wrong, but I strongly suspect the system was first installed on different hardware and then the disk moved over to this production server. ...The "console" is seldom important but right now it is, and I need to use it! As it is you can make out some things but running a visual editor would be "beyond challenging"

The reason I need to get to the console is too lengthy to describe here, but I HAVE been able to get the system to boot as it is, and I can get to it from the network to fix the video configuration. Once fixed, I'll then have to shut it down, reconfigure, reboot and THEN use the console!

For what it's worth, given what I CAN see on the screen, it's some sort of size vs refresh rate issue.

So, how do I tell not only grub (which is less important since it'll eventually do the right thing anyway) but a fairly recent Fedora Server version (it's at least as young as v 35) to just use a quite simple default? I figure, if the motherboard's splash screen looks great, then it's surely not the hardware!

If it matters, I really don't know if it's got a proper "desktop", like Gnome, but this issue kicks in before a desktop would start. However, it WOULD be nice to know how to select among resolution / ratio options sometime later, after it's "useful!"